# Import Term Set including Guid (unique identifier)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem, import, term-set

From our Sharepoint on premise server using a script I exported existing terms that also copies Guid for each term in LCID column of .csv file.

I'm trying to import term set to Sharepoint Online through a .csv file as available in sample format.

I was able to import Terms, but unique identifier (Guid) was not copied rather terms were assigned new guid. I want to keep Guid that was assigned to each term by Sharepoint on premise.

Is there a way to to import terms through .csv file but keep the Term Guid?

**Edit:** I just realized that setting Guid to LCID column does not make sense, but I'm still trying to find a way to import term including Guid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PnP.PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/) for exporting and importing taxonomies which will preserve Term IDs, TermSet IDs.

You can use [Export-PnPTermGroupToXml](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Export-PnPTermGroupToXml.html) command to export all the termsets from particular term group into XML file.

Then you can use same XML file as input for importing Terms to SharePoint Online using [Import-PnPTermGroupFromXml](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Import-PnPTermGroupFromXml.html) command.

Hope it will helpful to you and if so please mark this as answer or vote this answer for better reach of this knowledge to other people.